# Sulla presenza di 'certa' in 'destinate a morte certa o a schiavitù'

Tags: grammar

> Sì, ma sono giovani ragazze, nonché cittadine italiane, lì destinate a morte certa o a schiavitù. Ciò era raccapricciante.

Il 'certa' dopo 'morte' confligge con la 'o' che segue e che prospetta un'alternativa o la frase è corretta così com'è?

Comment: Direi che il *certa* è di troppo.

Answer (score 5):

Non conosco bene la situazione a cui si riferisce la frase, ma in astratto è certamente possibile avere un'alternativa tra “morte certa” e schiavitù («o ti facciamo schiavo o ti buttiamo nell'oceano infestato da squali»), contrapposta a un'alternativa tra, diciamo, “morte possibile” e schiavitù («o ti facciamo schiavo o scendi in arena e combatti»).

Answer (score 1):

Gran bella domanda. È un errore di concetto, non di grammatica: "certa" è errato, poiché se può accadere o la morte o la schiavitù, la morte non è certa.

Comment: L'interpretazione non è questa. L'aggettivo "certa" non si contrappone qui alla schiavitù come possibile alternativa, bensì alla morte "plausibile". Vale a dire, le alternative qui erano morire o esser schiavi, dove morire era una cosa certa, non plausibile.